# How to implement a persistent counter in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to have a "last known" counter in Python that will survive after server reboot?

I have a python script that is launched on schedule (by cron). It read files with document IDs in predefined format. I need to remember last processed document ID in order to ignore all the previous ones if there are any.

Comment: Save it in a database/file?

Comment: I'd prefer not to install Oracle to save just one counter :) Looking for a lightweight solution :)

Comment: As for file, that a good idea, but not cross-platform.

Comment: You don't have to install Oracle; it's a little expensive... you could use SQLite, as for the file, you could save it on a network share, which is accessible by whatever platform you want.

Comment: What? Saving to a file isn't cross-platform? How?

Comment: An alternative might employ file mtimes in some way, or marking files somehow (e.g. changing permissions, perhaps changing to read-only to indicate that it's been processed and aught not to be touched). Not sure whether those would be suitable.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, I mean that it's not guaranteed that cron user has writable home directory. Sorry, that was not obvious from my comment

Comment: @Antonio: well, whatever you arrange, you'll need to have access to a writable location *somewhere*.

Answer (score 5):

Any value you want to survive a reboot needs to be put into persistent storage - i.e. the disk. This means a file of some sort, whether that's a simple plaintext file or a database file is up to you. You've indicated in the comments you don't feel this is "cross-platform", but it would be a strange platform indeed that didn't have some sort of filesystem support.

If you need structured storage then SQLite support is built-in with Python's [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module. However, it sounds like you just need to store a single ID so a simple file will suffice. I suggest something like this:

```
import os

DATA_FILENAME = os.path.expanduser("~/document-counter.txt")

def update_document_id(new_id):
    with open(DATA_FILENAME, "w") as fd:
        fd.write(new_id + "\n")

def retrieve_document_id():
    with open(DATA_FILENAME, "r") as fd:
        return fd.readline().strip()
```

You should probably do better error checking (e.g. catch the exception that's thrown if the file doesn't exist, etc.) but this gives you the idea of how simple the solution can be. You're better off catching exceptions ([EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) is often considered more Pythonic than [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl)) but if you want to explicitly check for, say, file existence then that's easy in a portable manner too:

```
if not os.path.exists(DATA_FILENAME):
    print "No file found. Deal with it."
```

If you need to add more data fields later, I suggest SQLite - it's convenient, robust and allows you to interoperate with applications in other languages should that be required in the future. Plus you can use the standalone SQLite command-line client to manipulate your data if you need to. You just provide a filename to the `sqlite3.connect()` method so it's essentially as easy as opening a file, it's just you can then throw SQL at it.

However, for a simple single ID I'd just stick to a plaintext file - you really don't get much more compatible than that.

Comment: I would consider using the `shelve` module, in the standard library, to be simpler still than that.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with `shelve` at all for simple cases like this. Personally I prefer either plaintext files or SQLite files because they're easier to support in other languages, but I totally accept that the OP didn't specify that as a requirement. His concern with a cross-platform solution made me think perhaps a cross-language solution might appeal to him, was all. For structured data `shelve` is surely better than rolling your own plaintext format - I just personally prefer SQLite unless I need to store Python classes or similar (then `shelve` is better, of course).

Comment: And it's quite likely that there will be other persistent data requirements already in existence or which will pop up. A proper database is certainly typically going to be a wise idea. Something like `ConfigParser` would be more readily cross-language than `shelve`.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a database or a file. You might choose to write it to a file; you might choose to use `ConfigParser` or `csv`; or you might choose to use [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) (it's nice and simple to use; if this is all you want persistent storage for, it might be the most straightforward). There are other options too; take a look at what the [standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) offers to get a feel for it. You will still need to specify the file you wish to store the results in, and permissions will need to be appropriate, but that shouldn't be difficult.